# Why does strlen() appear to return <void> in the VC++ debugger?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I have a string in C++ of type `const char*` passed as argument to strlen, but it returns void.

it goes like

```
strlen(astruct.string);
```

Thanks..

EDIT: Did some checking,

```
strlen("test");
```

still gives void.. why?

EDIT: Here's the image
http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/1808/strlen.png

Sorry for being unclear previously. Formatting was not working quite well. Anyway, the confusion was solved by both Evan Teran and Vlad Romascanu. Also take a look at Brian R. Bondy's answer.

Thanks. Feel free to close.

Comment: How do you know it returns void?

Comment: you need to define what you mean by "returning void" since it can't. And that image you posted is WAY to small to actually view.

Comment: For a start, your image is rubbish, take it again at a decent resolution. Secondly, add more descriptive information (compile-time or run-time error, what is the EXACT reason you think it's misbehaving). Your question as it stands, makes no sense. Don't pass char** to strlen, it needs char*.

Comment: Ok.. Damn jpeg compression.. There's no error of any sort.. Just that it says strlen returned <void> in the variables window of visual c++ 6.0

Comment: In your image it doesn't return void, its mean the debugger was unable to get the return value, probably because the compiler inlined it.

Comment: What's up with people downvoting and voting to close? Geez.. Anyway, thanks xhantt.

Comment: Hey krebstar - sorry some people were rather blunt with you.  Maybe your company will consider moving to a newer compiler if they realize that newer compilers are free, and that VC6 can cause problems?

Comment: Need MFC.. so no free compilers.

Comment: I believe you can use visual c++ 2008 with MFC...

Comment: But that's not free. And I can't just deviate from the my company issued tools, okay? If they change it, great, but for now I'm stuck with it.

Comment: well, you've got to work with what they say. Though like I said, I would show them modern alternatives: http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/

Comment: Just a question, if I put strlen("Something") in the watch pane of VS2008, does it correctly show the return value? Is this thing specific to MSVC6?

Comment: krebstar it does not return the value.  It also doesn't handle #defines properly

Comment: Thanks for retitle'ing greg..

Comment: This is a valid question and should be re-opened, please vote to re-open

Comment: Well, it seems to have already been answered, brian..

Comment: Valid questions shouldn't be closed though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to your screen shot: your debugger is displaying `<void>` for `strlen(...)` when in fact it should display an error.

You cannot call methods and display their results in the debugger watch.  The debugger will only display existing variables and data.  It cannot invoke arbitrary methods on demand since the methods can alter the state of the program being debugged in ways that were not anticipated by either the author of the code nor by the debugger.

What you can do is, in your code, temporarily add:

```
size_t tmp_len = strlen(struc.string);
```

then compile, and add tmp_len to the watch.

Comment: Dude, I know.. But in my code, it returns void.. Is there any reason why it would do this?

Comment: Does this mean that when you attempt to compile <<size_t x = strlen("abcd")>> you actually get a compilation error like "cannot assign void to size_t"?

Comment: Are you checking the length in the function or in the return from the function?  Sound like your return is using data on the stack.

Comment: I don't think he added a "strlen("whatever");" to the watch. This looks like he pulled up the "automatics" window (the left one clearly is) where is says "strlen returned <void>"

Comment: Yes, that's right evan, but I also did a strlen("whatever") in the watch.. both said <void>..

Comment: Indeed, so while Vlad's answer is true, mine is also correct.

Comment: Yes, thanks.. Too bad I can't mark both correct

Comment: You can call functions in the watch.  Please see my description for what I believe to be the correct answer.

Comment: For example:  int testfunc(char *) { return 5; }.   You can call testfunc("hi") in the watch and it will return 5.

Answer (score 6):

You are confused by the crappy debugger of visual studio 6.0. Don't rely on this. It likely couldn't get the return value due to inlining or something similar.

Print the value out to get the real value.

EDIT: Also, from your example, it seems that you may not be storing the result of strlen anyway. This also may be a reason why the debugger isn't seeing the return value. It's entirely possible that the compiler decided that it doesn't need to actually execute the strlen if you aren't using the value.

NOTE: at this point there is no real excuse for **still** using VC++ 6.0. It is an ancient compiler and IDE which is an embarrassingly poor c++ compiler. The newer versions of the visual c++ compiler are free (without the IDE), use them.

Comment: Why do you have to be so rude about it? My company uses VC6, okay? It's not like I can just change the software on company property. Okay, so I work for a crappy company, doesn't mean you should be mean about it.

Comment: This is actually the right answer. But you could be nicer.. >.<

Comment: I wasn't trying to be rude, I was attempting to state the facts about the toolset you are using. If you are being forced to use it, I'm sorry to hear that. You may want to consider bringing up the antiquity of the toolset to your team.

Comment: Ok. I don't think I can do that, anyway, thanks.

Comment: -1 incorrect reason stated for why the debugger displays <void> when a method invocation is typed in the watch

Comment: @Vlad, I beg to differ, the left window in the screen shot is clearly the "automatics" window showing what was *executed*

Comment: +1 cause I can't choose two answers

Comment: @Evan, you are correct about the left pane, and it is most definitely a misfeature of VC for displaying <void> there; the right pane is an actual watch, and VC should not have accepted the insertions. +1.

Comment: I think we've collectively solved this for you.

Answer (score 4):

strlen is not of return type void, it's your debugger that is not giving the right message.

**Why your debbuger is showing void?**

The implementation of strlen that you are using is probably wrapped around a #define strlen someothername_strlen.

The debugger probably does not support #define properly or some other modifiers on the function.

You will have to do something like iLen = strlen("test") then check iLen in your watch.

Normally you can call functions in your watch.  For example try to define the following function then call it in your watch:

```
int testFunc(char*)
{
  return 5;
}
```

You will probably get 5 in your watch as a result.

Comment: I did the code sample you have, you are right. When I right click on strlen and click go to definition it brings up the STRING.H file in VC98\Include. it defines strlen as "size_t  __cdecl strlen(const char *);"

Comment: I get the same results as krebstar. It's probably that the CRT is not built with the right debug settings (or maybe that strlen() is an assembly routine).  If I have a myStrlen() function that does nothing but wrap a strlen() call, the watch window displays the result on that just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the additional verification michael..

Answer (score 0):

strlen returns an integer, so I assume you mean it returns "0".

Also, the way that you specify your data type, I can't quite tell if it's a const char * or const char **. If it's the latter, then you need to make sure you're dereferencing the ** to a single *.

My guess is that the string starts with a null byte, which is why it's returning 0.

Comment: Hi, no, it returns void, not 0.. I don't think the string starts with a null byte.. actually its a file path.. it starts with a D..

data type is const char *..

Comment: It can't return void, it returns whatever size_t is.  Perhaps your cstring header file is bad?

Comment: Try adding a line before strlen that says printf("%hhu", *astruct.string); Report what this printed. My guess is that it prints "0".

Comment: You can't return void, it is the lack of a return value.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, functions always return a value of the type they are declared to return. Since the `strlen` function declaration looks something like this:

```
size_t strlen(const char *);
```

the only thing it can *possibly* return is a `size_t`. The compiler uses this information at compile time to determine how to handle the return value when you call the function. The point here is that if the `strlen` function is declared as above, it cannot decide to return `void` sometimes and a value of type `size_t` other times.

This is generally a characteristic of statically typed languages like C++. In dynamically typed languages (Perl, Python, Ruby, PHP, etc) a function can decide to return a value of any type each time it is called.

Answer (score -2):

It can't return void. Void is the lack of a return value, so you can't, err, return it.

How do you check for void anyway? Void isn't a value. Please demonstrate how you are getting void. Is it compile time or run time?

If you do in fact have a system where `strlen` is declared with a `void` return type, run as fast as you can in the other direction.